# characterization of singularities of dynamic system

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields, singularity-theory

Is there any characterization of singularities of a dynamical system in ${R}^2$?

How to characterize singularities of vector fields?

Can You suggest any book which explains geometrically?

Thanks, advance.

Comment: Can you provide examples?

Comment: Sink, source type of singularities

Comment: Thanks, @Moo I need to understand how bad can be a neighborhood of singularities. I can understand when it is usual non-degenarate.